# Factory method to instantiate instance of objects used in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, factory, generic-programming

I have the following classes.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

      protected String value1;

      public void setValue1(String value1) {
           this.value1 = value1;
      }

}

public abstract class ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractClass{

}

public abstract class ConcreteClass2 extends AbstractClass {

}

public class FactoryOfAbstractClass {

   public AbstractClass newInstance(Class responseType) {
      if (responseType == ConcreteClass1.class) {
         return new ConcreteClass1();
      } else if (responseType == ConcreteClass2.class) {
         return new ConcreteClass2();
      }
      return null;

}

public abstract class ServiceClass<T extends AbstractClass> {

   public T method1 (String arg1, String arg2, Class responseType) {

      //Some operations resulting in a variable called value1
      String value1= someOp();
      T result = FactoryOfAbstractClass.newInstance(responseType);
      result.setValue1(value1);
      return result;

   }
```

}

In line  `T result = FactoryOfAbstractClass.newInstance(responseType);` I get a compilation error saying I need to typecast the object I'm getting to T. I don't understand the **compilation error** since my factory method is returning an instance of Abstract class and the service class's generic `T extends AbstractClass`.

The compilation issue goes away once I cast it to T. But I don't understand why we need to typecast it in the first place. Why is the typecasting needed?

The other option is to not use a Factory and instead go with `responseType.newInstance()`. But that internally uses reflections and I want to avoid them.
Is there any other approach i can take for this?

Comment: Don't use raw types: `Class` should be `Class<? extends AbstractClass>`.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand the compilation error since my factory method is returning an instance of Abstract class and the service class's generic T extends AbstractClass

Let's replace `AbstractClass` with `Car` for a more understandable explanation. Suppose a programmer create a `ServiceClass<Mercedes>`(Mercedes is a typeof Car, right?). `FactoryOfAbstractClass.newInstance()`'s return type is `Car`. So the compiler has no idea of the concrete type of Car returned by this method. It could be a Mercedes, but it could also be a Ford, or a Peugeot, or a Volskwagen. But you assign the result to `T` (which, in this case, is `Mercedes`). So that can't compile without a cast.

Frankly, this factory is completely unnecessary. Since the caller is supposed to pass the class to use anyway, you could just take an instance of that class instead of a factory, and thus let the caller create the instance. Or you could take a `Supplier<AbstractClass>` as argument, and the caller would just have to pass `ConcreteClass1::new`. That would make the code simpler, safer, and more extensible (since you wouldn't be limited to only two known subclasses).

Comment: That's all about generic type erasure, you could get more details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with type erasure.

Comment: Compiler have to replace `T` with something. 
In this scenario `public <T extends AbstractClass> T method1(...)` `T` is bounded by AbsctractClass only, so `T` in compiler time would be replaced with `AbstractClass`. Replacing `T` with something is type erasure, isn't it?

Your example with different car types is just about that.

Comment: No, it's not. If types were not erased, you would have the same compilation error, simply because the AbstractClass instance returned by the factory could be of another type than T, whether T is erased or not.

Comment: The reason why an instance cannot be passed is because in some methods inside the service class, there is a requirement to return List<T> instead of just T. In this method in the example, yes you are right, an instance can be passed.